# Angular interceptor spinner

Tags: angular

Estoy tratando de crear un spinner con un interceptor, el problema es que no me funciona la propiedad que creo de tipo Subject(), cuando invoco su metodo next para cambiar su estado.

**Servicio**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SpinnerService {
  inProgress = new Subject<boolean>();
  constructor() { }    

  // mostrar el spining 
  show(){
     this.inProgress.next(true)
  }

  // ocultar el spining
  hide(){
    this.inProgress.next(false)
  }
}
```

**Componente Spinner**

```
<app-spinner [inProgress]="inProgress"></app-spinner>
```

**Dentro de este app spiner esta el siguiente HTML**

```
<mat-spinner *ngIf="inProgress | async" mode="indeterminate"></mat-spinner>
```

**Componente TS**

```
@Input() inProgress = new Subject<boolean>()
```

El input se lo paso del siguiente componente padre, que es el que invoca al servicio y metodo show

**Componente Padre**

```
inProgress = new Subject<boolean>();
constructor(
private seriesService: SeriesService,
private sesionService: SesionService,
private dialog: MatDialog,
private route: Router,
private spinnerService: SpinnerService) 
{
  // if(!this.id) this.route.navigate(['/login'])
  this.inProgress = this.spinnerService.inProgress;
}
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.spinnerService.show();
}
```

**El error seria que siempre esta en false la variable inProgress**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Gente ya lo resolvi.
El problema esta en el **pipe** async" mode="indeterminate"

Como lo estaba probando sin el interceptor, siempre estaba en falso por el async, estaba esperando resolucion de algo y nunca iba a llegar. Al sacarlo ya anda sin problemas.

Ahora cuando use este servicio y componente con el interceptor, **si hay que agregar el pipe**